# How to exclude the comma operator from an expression in Grammar-Kit?

Tags: intellij-plugin, comma-operator, grammar-kit

I'm writing an IntelliJ language plugin for a C-derived language which includes the comma operator. I'm using Grammar-Kit to generate the parser. Where the formal grammar has a lot of nested *expression* productions, I've rewritten them using [Grammar-Kit's priority-based expression parsing](https://github.com/JetBrains/Grammar-Kit/blob/master/HOWTO.md#24-compact-expression-parsing-with-priorities), so my *expression* production looks like this:

```
expression ::= comma_expression
 | assignment_expression
 | conditional_expression
 | eor_expression
 | xor_expression
 | and_expression
 | equality_expression
 | relation_expression
 | add_expression
 | mul_expression
 | prefix_expression
 | postfix_group
 | primary_expression

comma_expression ::= expression ',' expression {pin=2}
// etc.
```

This works fine in itself, but there are places in the grammar where I need to parse an *expression* that can't be a *comma expression*. Function calls are one example of this:

```
function_call_expression ::= identifier '(' ('void'|<<comma_list expression>>)? ')'
private meta comma_list ::= <<p>> (',' <<p>>)*
```

A function argument can't be a *comma expression*, because that would be ambiguous with the comma separating the next argument. (In the grammar as I have it now, it always parses as a single comma expression.) The formal grammar deals with this by specifying that each function argument must be an *assignment expression*, because their *assignment expression* includes all the expressions with tighter precedence. That doesn't work for the Grammar-Kit priority-based grammar, because an *assignment expression* really does have to include an assignment.

The same applies to initializers, where allowing a *comma expression* would lead to an ambiguous parse in cases like `int x=1, y;`.

How should I deal with this situation? I'd like to keep using the priority-based parse to keep a shallow PSI tree, but also avoid manually rewriting the PSI tree for function calls to turn a`CommaExpression` into an argument list.

Comment: > That doesn't work for the Grammar-Kit priority-based grammar, because an assignment expression really does have to include an assignment.
So `assignment_expression` cannot be an argument of `function_call_expression` ? Maybe try `conditional_expression` then, because it includes all the expressions with tighter precedence too.